# WhitespaceAfter conflict with GenericWhitespace

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am using both of the above checks. Is there a way to make it so WhitespaceAfter forces space after commas, EXCEPT when it is in generics? ie I want this to be valid.

```
public void function(String a, String b) {
    Map<String,String> data = Hashtable<String,String>();
    // etc...
}
```

ie space after comma in functions declaration is sensible, but putting it inside the generics seems strange. Especially in the case of this example, adding the space seems to make this harder to read:

```
public void fn(Connection c, Map<String,Object>>items) {
}
```

Comment: I prefer `Map<String, String>` over `Map<String,String>`. The space makes it more readable imho, especially with longer classnames.

Comment: I knew at least one person would say that. While a poll would be interesting, my question is about how to achieve the above.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer ;) My prediction would be 90% or more for whitespace. Poll here: [http://strawpoll.me/52394](http://strawpoll.me/52394)

Comment: Sometimes bending to peer pressure is worthwhile ;)

Comment: I also disagree with your new example. Adding a comma would increase readability imho. It is clear that is is the generic type and not a parameter because there is no identifier after the type. Also `c` is a poor variable name, if it had a meaningful it would be more readable (with the comma).

Comment: I've written a short blog post about your question. You can check it out here [johnny.lordo.net/2013/05/java-code-style-commas-and-whitespace.html](http://goo.gl/nV5gC)

Comment: Im also hoping for some more poll results. Very interested to see what people think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems not possible with checkstyle to achieve your goal. `WhitespaceAfter` rule doesn't have any options to exclude commas within type parameters. Perhaps you can write your own rule to do that by extending or rewriting the `WhitespaceAfter` rule, refering to http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html

Comment: The fact that is not possible might be a sign that my current way is not used very often (:

Comment: @Jacob: Also on the poll (here: [http://strawpoll.me/52394](http://strawpoll.me/52394)) it's starting to lose :D

Comment: @Jacob Well, the number of vote is too small. Don't be disappointed. Anyway, rules should be as simple and consistent as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot easily be done using Checkstyle out of the box, so let me suggest an alternative (It is in fact what I do in my commercial projects):

Disable all Checkstyle rules related to code formatting, and use the automatic code formatter of your IDE instead. Many IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) can format your code whenever you save the editor contents.
Then you can configure the automatic formatter to handle your case. I just checked the Eclipse Juno code formatting options; it can do just what you want - no space after a comma in a generics declaration but a space after a comma everywhere else.

This approach has added benefits:

- The developers don't have to deal with annoying Checkstyle messages concerning code formatting anymore.
- Wrong code formatting is no longer possible.
- You get consistent formatting across all developers, which makes the calculation of diffs etc. much easier.

I am aware that this approach may not be possible in your case, but it is one way that I know works very well, and it does solve your issue without having to code a custom check.